# Restoring Plesk's Apache and Nginx settings

Tags: apache, nginx, backup, restore, plesk

I'm working on an automation process to deploy a new server with the same configuration than my production server, which uses **Plesk 12.5**.

I backup my production system configuration everyday (server level, configuration only), and wish to use those backups to restore Plesk on my new server. Everything goes approximately smooth, and the domains are re-created on my new server, as well as the FTP accounts, the DBs and the scheduled tasks.

Only, **it does NOT set the Apache and Nginx settings again** on the new server. Actually, when I check the backup files up, those settings are nowhere to be found, which is very mysterious, as I believe it's a cornerstone for websites' URL handling.

**How can I *actually* backup and restore Apache and Nginx settings for my domains ?**

Answer (score 0):

Additional Apache and Nginx directives are included into `Domain configuration` part of the backup. You can find `httpd.conf` and `vhost_nginx.conf` files in `backup_conf_<date_and_time>.tgz` archive in the backup directory.

Indeed, they should be restored.

Comment: This is odd: my backup only contains a backup_info_xxxxxxxxx.xml for the server, and one per domain. I just found out those xml *actually* contains additionalSettings (Apache HTTP), additionalSslSettings (Apache HTTPS) and additionalNginxSettings (Nginx), encoded in base64. So they *should* be restored...